# How to get the length in km of a polyline from react- native-maps?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

So i´ve created a map, with a polyline inside of it:

```
import React from 'react';
import MapView, {Polyline} from 'react-native-maps';

function TrackDetailScreen({navigation}) {

return (
    <>
        <MapView    
            initialRegion={
                { 
                    [{latitude: 23,longitude: 83 },{latitude: 25,longitude: 86 }, ],
                    latitudeDelta: 0.01,
                    longitudeDelta: 0.01,
                  


                }
            }
            > 
            <Polyline  strokeColor='#fc5e13'
           strokeWidth={5} coordinates={track.locations.map(loc => loc.coords)}/>
        </MapView>
    </>
)
}

export default TrackDetailScreen;
```

Now I want to figure out the distance of the polyline i´ve just built.

How can I tackle that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The proper way to calculate the distance between two points given their coordinates is to use the [haversine](https://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html) formula, because you must consider the earth curvature.

```
function haversine(coords1, coords2) {
  const R = 6371e3; // metres
  const φ1 = coords1.lat * Math.PI/180; // φ, λ in radians
  const φ2 = coords2.lat * Math.PI/180;
  const Δφ = (coords2.lat-coords1.lat) * Math.PI/180;
  const Δλ = (coords2.lon-coords1.lon) * Math.PI/180;

  const a = Math.sin(Δφ/2) * Math.sin(Δφ/2) +
          Math.cos(φ1) * Math.cos(φ2) *
          Math.sin(Δλ/2) * Math.sin(Δλ/2);
  const c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1-a));

  return R * c; // in metres
}
```

Full disclosure: I stole this code from here: https://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html

Once you have this, you can simply iterate over the points of your polyline and incrementally calculate the sum:

```
let totalDistance = 0
for (let i = 1; i < track.locations.length; i++) {
  totalDistance += haversine(track.locations[i-1].coords, track.locations[i].coords)
}
```

---

It's worth noting that for short distances, you can obtain an **estimate** of the distance with simple geometry, without considering the earth curvature. It should be way faster to calculate and is probably better if your polyline contains a ton of points with a short distance beetwen them.

```
function distance(coords1, coords2) {
   const latDiffSquared = Math.pow((coords1.lat - coords2.lat), 2)
   const lonDiffSquared = Math.pow((coords1.lon - coords2.lon), 2)
   return Math.sqrt(latDiffSquared + lonDiffSquared)
}
```